# Datasnap server with multiple database connections

Tags: database, delphi, database-connection, firebird, datasnap

I am creating a new version of my *Datasnap* server for *Firemonkey* apps to connect to in *Delphi 10.2 Tokyo*.

My main issue is that the *Datasnap* server must be able to connect to **multiple *Firebird* databases**. The apps will give a parameter to the server so it knows which one to use.

For know I use an .INI file for administrating my Firebird databases. On creation of the server it reads all the locations of the database files and settings.

**What is the best way to safely connect to the databases in your opinion?**

I've had a few ideas my self:

1. On device connect create new connection component and then connect to
   database that the app has set in parameter. After the device disconnects close the connection and free the component from memory.
2. After reading the INI file create the connection components and put them in a list. Then when a device connects search for the connection with the parameter the app sends and then open the database connection. Then after the device disconnects close the connection.
3. Create new `TDSServer` per database with a set database connection and add to
   list. When device connects search for the server it needs to use with the parameter the app sends. No further database connection handling is necessary.
   Only opening the connection and closing.
4. Or something else entirely? Maybe multi-threading?

---

#### Remarks

1. If a new database is added to the INI file the server is restarted so it reads all settings again. So no need for accounting for new databases runtime.
2. I do also want to use database transactions arround calling different methods in the server. The apps send when to start/commit/rollback the transaction.

Comment: Have you tried your ideas? Have you recognized any problems? I don't know whether `TDSServer` supports multiple database connections at the same time. This might be a limiting point.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann right now I have a server that creates a new connection everytime a device connects. But it's combined with multiple threads. It searches a thread pool for the right thread for the connection. But this gives a lot of lag.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code snippets? Maybe, your thread pool search has a flaw.

Comment: Furthermore, creating a separate connection for each connected device can be a problem in terms of memory consumption, depending on the firebird server type you are using.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann getting relevant code snippets is pretty hard to do. There are a lot of custom components used and such. I also thought a new connection per device could be a problem for the performance